# ASP.NET cannot access non-aspx files without logging in (.js, .html etc)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, security, authentication, authorization

I started a new solution with a website project and a logic project for all my class files.

I copied the web.config file I use for all my other projects and just changed the database name in the connection string. When I run this project to be debugged, it won't let me access any files until I login. This includes javascript files, html files, css files etc.

On all my other projects the only files which require a login by the user to access are `.aspx` files and `.asmx` files. The web.config security settings on all several of my projects are as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/Default.aspx" name="ADMINAUTH2" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

If I set test.htm as my start page, when I run the debugger the url heads straight to:
`http://localhost:2154/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2ftest.htm`

In VS on my solution exporler under script documents that are being loaded, any javascript file is shown as: `Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Functions.js` etc, and css files are not applied.

I have tried creating a new web.config file and only adding my auth properties and connection string but to no avail.

I am utterly confused as this works on all my other projects, just not this latest one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deploying this project to IIS or are you just running it from Visual Studio?

Authentication rules specified in the `web.config` apply to all files which are processed by the ASP.NET ISAPI filter. By default in IIS this is only things like `.aspx` and `.asmx`, etc - as you expect. However, the Visual Studio web server processes *everything* through ASP.NET, so the authentication rules apply to all files.

On the flip-side, this information can be quite useful when you actually *do* want to secure static assets in production - do so simply by setting IIS to have ASP.NET process those file extensions.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense as I am not running this project through IIS. This is a small side project and I didn't want to move my main project off IIS but it looks like I might have to. 

Thanks for the answer!